# how to get result array with getJson CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

my code :
model :

```
function get_all_transaksi_proses() {   
        $rs = $this->db->query("SELECT a.id_transaksi, ETC");
        return $rs;
    }
```

control :

```
public function ambilDataTransaksi() {
            $data=$this->transaksi->get_all_transaksi_proses();
             echo json_encode(array("result" => $data->result_array()));
        }
```

view :

```
$.getJSON("<?php base_url();?>transaksiDigorCont/ambilDataTransaksi", function(data) {
        alert("jhjh");

    });
```

this my code but it cant show alert("jhjh"), so it can't in to function(data) ?

Comment: please use your firebug to check whether your are getting json response

Comment: what happens when you execute above script? You have written that when you call `get_all_transaksi_proses()` via model then it can't. But what happens? Also use [get_class_methods](http://php.net/manual/en/function.get-class-methods.php) to get list of all the functions of a class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be doing like:

```
$.getJSON( "<?php echo base_url(); ?>controllername/somefunction", function( data ) {
   //do something with data
});
```

and in your controller, create a function say, '`somefunction`', and

```
//controller code
function somefunction() {
 //load model if not already done in constructor
 //get data from model
  $data = $this->your_model->get_all_transaksi_proses();
  echo json_encode($data);
}
```

Comment: i try to implement it, but getJson cant in to function (data)
 $.getJSON("<?php base_url();?>transaksiDigorCont/ambilDataTransaksi", function(data) {
        alert("jhjh");
        $("#dataku").empty();

Comment: you missed echo in <?php base_url();?> .. change to <?php echo base_url();?>

Answer (score 0):

See the [$.getJSON](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/) documentation:

```
jQuery.getJSON( url [, data ] [, success( data, textStatus, jqXHR ) ] )
```

It expects a URL as the first argument.